# Minko - Android light issue

Tags: android, c++, colors, light, minko

I am working with minko and seem to be facing a light issue with Android.
I managed to compile for linux64, Android and html a modified code (based on the tutorials provided by Minko). I simply load and rotate 4 .obj files (the pirate one provided and 3 found on turbosquid for demo purposes only).

The correct result is viewed in the linux64 and html version but the Android one has a "redish" light thrown into it, although the binaries are being generated from the same c++ code.

Here are some pics to demonstrate the problem:

linux64 :

http://tinypic.com/r/qzm2s5/8

Android version :

http://tinypic.com/r/23mn0p3/8

(Couldn’t link the html version but it is close to the linux64 one.)

Here is the part of the code related to the light :

```
        // create the spot light node
    auto spotLightNode = scene::Node::create("spotLight");

    // change the spot light position
    //spotLightNode->addComponent(Transform::create(Matrix4x4::create()->lookAt(Vector3::zero(), Vector3::create(0.1f, 2.f, 0.f)))); //ok linux - html
    spotLightNode->addComponent(Transform::create(Matrix4x4::create()->lookAt(Vector3::zero(), Vector3::create(0.1f, 8.f, 0.f))));

    // create the point light component
    auto spotLight = SpotLight::create(.15f, .4f);    //ok linux and html

    // update the spot light component attributes
    spotLight->diffuse(4.5f);   //ori - ok linux - html

    // add the component to the spot light node
    spotLightNode->addComponent(spotLight);

    //sets a red color to our spot light
    //spotLightNode->component<SpotLight>()->color()->setTo(2.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f); 

    // add the node to the root of the scene graph
    rootNode->addChild(spotLightNode);
```

As you can notice the `color()->setTo` has been turned off and works for all except Android (clean and rebuild). Any idea what might be the source of the problem here ?

Any pointer would be much appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: In case it matters, tested on an LG LG-D855 official Kitkat 4.4.2 rom  
Kernel verion : 3.4.0  
LG software version : V10g-AME-XX

Comment: issue remained after upgrading to official LG version : V10i-AME-XX (not latest for this phone).

PS: binary compiled using master branch.

Comment: same for : V10I-AME-XX

Comment: same for : V10o-AME-XX (Next update is OS upgrade)
which means master issue is present for Kitkat version of LG g3

Answer (score 0):

Can you test it on other Android devices or with a more recent ROM and give us the result? LG-D855 (LG G3) is powered by an Adreno 330: those GPUs are known to have GLSL compiling deffects, especially with loops and/or structs like we use in [Phong.fragment.glsl on the master branch](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/master/framework/asset/effect/Phong.fragment.glsl).

The [Phong.fragment.glsl on the dev branch](https://github.com/aerys/minko/blob/dev/framework/asset/effect/Phong.fragment.glsl) has been heavily refactored to fix this (for directional lights only for now).

**You could try the dev branch and a directional light and see if it fixes the issue.** Be careful though: the dev branch introduces the beta 3, with some API changes. The biggest API change being the math API now using GLM, and the *.effect file format. The best way to go is simply to update your math code to use the new API, everything else should be straight forward.

Comment: Indeed, the problem seems specific to this phone so far as older phones are rendering correctly. Also yes, there is a pending system update but i rather not do it now. Since you suggest another route i will try that first.  PS: I am no expert with shaders / fragment files, but i assume i can't just copy paste some files and recompile my code but i will have to 'git clone' the dev Branch entirely and rebuild the framework, right ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't compile the dev branch for android using **make -j 4 config=android_release**.  I get errors similar to :  `error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'const mat4& {aka const glm::detail::tmat4x4<float, (glm::precision)0u>&}' from expression of type 'const float'`  


Also I am unable to compile the examples and tutorials for linux and html (but i guess that's on purpose since premake5.sh was moved to bin ?)

Comment: Some examples/tutorials don't work yet in dev because of the new math API. You can look at the "lights" example for a working example. I've edited my answer.

Comment: The very few examples that compile for linux64 don't run (example assimp opens a window and closes immediately).   Nevertheless, i managed to modify my code to use the new API and it compiles fine, however on launch it also crashes with a segmentation fault at :  `sceneMan->assets()->loader()->load();`  Any idea what might be wrong ? (Same asset folder works perfectly with non dev branch).
Thx.

Comment: create another question for that